# Play music in flash player by clicking play button which is in the web page

Tags: html, flash, button, playback

I want to play the music file in flash player (which is embedded obviously) by clicking the play button which is in the web page (not in flash player).

How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [`ExternalInterface.addCallback()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#addCallback%28%29).

> Registers an ActionScript method as callable from the container. After a successful invocation of `addCallback()`, the registered function in the player can be called by JavaScript or ActiveX code in the container.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make your own flas player you could look into the [yahoo webplayer](http://webplayer.yahoo.com/).  It does what you are describing... it puts a play button on the html page and then when you click it, it opens the player and begins to play.  There are also a lot of other features like playlists and things you can use too.  They have good info about using and show the code of exactly how to utilize it.